Facebook SDK returned an error: Cross-site request forgery validation failed. Required param "state" missing codeigniter 4
This error arises when the Facebook SDK detects a potential security risk during the login process. The state parameter acts as a crucial security measure to prevent Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) attacks. It ensures that the request to obtain a Facebook access token originates from your legitimate application and not a malicious source.
class FacebookAuthController extends Controller
{
protected $helpers = ['url', 'session']; // Load the URL and session helper
private $fb; // Declare Facebook object as a private property

public function __construct()
{
    include_once APPPATH . "Libraries/vendor/autoload.php";

    // Initialize Facebook SDK in the constructor
    $this->fb = new Facebook([
        'app_id' => '=',
        'app_secret' => '',
        'default_graph_version' => 'v11.0',
    ]);
}

public function login()
{
    // Use the previously initialized Facebook object from the property
    $fb = $this->fb;

    // Redirect to Facebook's OAuth consent screen
    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
    $redirectURL = base_url('auth/facebook/callback');

    // Generate a CSRF token and save it in session
    $csrfToken = bin2hex(random_bytes(32)); // Generate a random token
    session()->set('csrf_token', $csrfToken);

    $permissions = ['email']; // Specify the permissions you need
    $loginURL = $helper->getLoginUrl($redirectURL, $permissions);

    // Append the CSRF token to the login URL as state parameter
    $loginURL .= '&state=' . $csrfToken;

    return redirect()->to($loginURL);
}

public function callback()
{
    // Use the previously initialized Facebook object from the property
    $fb = $this->fb;

    try {
        $accessToken = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper()->getAccessToken();
        if (!$accessToken) {
            throw new Exception('No access token received');
        }

        // Validate CSRF token
        $state = $this->request->getGet('state');
        $csrfToken = session()->get('csrf_token');
        if ($state !== $csrfToken) {
            throw new Exception('CSRF token mismatch');
        }

        // Implement your Facebook API logic using $accessToken and $fb
        // ... (e.g., get user data, store access token, create user account)
        $userData = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,name,email', $accessToken);
        $facebookData = $userData->getData();

        // Example usage (replace with your specific logic)
        if (isset($facebookData['email'])) {
            $email = $facebookData['email'];
            // ... (check user existence in your database, create account if needed) ...
        }

        // ... (Handle successful login) ...

    } catch (\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        // Handle Facebook API response error
        echo 'Facebook API Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
}

}`
Facebook SDK returned an error: Cross-site request forgery validation failed. Required param "state" missing.

The SDK itself expects the value to be stored in the session under the key state. And it uses $_SESSION to access the session data, so if you are using a framework that has a different mechanism to access session data, it might need some modifications.
